# Serialize numpy arrays into an npz string?

Tags: python, numpy, io

I'm looking for a way to generate a compressed binary string out of multiple numpy arrays with different types. :D
The method recommended in this question:

[Storing and loading numpy arrays as files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17574976/storing-and-loading-numpy-arrays-as-string)

Is to use the following:

```
np.savez_compressed('file_name_here.npz', arr_a = a, arr_b = b)
```

But the caveat is that I need the actual string directly and don't have a path to save it to. Is there any simple way to directly generate the binary string without saving to disk? Is there some kind of work around to do this?

Comment: On a side-note, in the docs it says `If keyword arguments are given, then filenames are taken from the keywords. If arguments are passed in with no keywords, then stored file names are arr_0, arr_1, etc.`, why does it speak of filenames when savez is supposed to save a single file?

Comment: `savez...` writes the data to a set of files, a different one for each variable.  These are packaged together into an archive, which may also be compressed.   This isn't designed to create a string buffer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could simply save the compressed array to a `StringIO` object and read it back,

```
from cStringIO import StringIO
import numpy as np

x = np.ones(10)

f = StringIO()
np.savez_compressed(f, x=x)
f.seek(0)
out = f.read()

print(out)
```

Comment: so `np.load(StringIO(out))['x']` would recover `x`.

Answer (score 0):

To save a numpy array as a **compressed string**, you can save the compressed array to an in-memory `io.BytesIO()`, and convert those bytes to a base64 string.

Then, to load, you do the opposite. Here are two handy functions I wrote to do this:

```py
import base64
import io
import numpy as np

def numpy_arr_to_zip_str(arr):
    f = io.BytesIO()
    np.savez_compressed(f, arr=arr)
    return base64.b64encode(f.getvalue())

def numpy_zip_str_to_arr(zip_str):
    f = io.BytesIO(base64.b64decode(zip_str))
    return np.load(f)['arr']
```

This is distinct from getting a bytesarray and passing that around. The base64-encoded string is portable across different programs which may or may not accept communication with bytes.